# Send HEAD http request with body to cause net/http error

Tags: http, go, error-handling

I would like [this](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-variables) exception to be caused:

> ```
> // ErrBodyNotAllowed is returned by ResponseWriter.Write calls
> // when the HTTP method or response code does not permit a
> // body.
> ErrBodyNotAllowed = errors.New("http: request method or response status code does not allow body")
> ```

When I send HEAD request with body using fiddler I get 400/504 error codes, but I don't see any error log in my application.

Comment: `ErrBodyNotAllowed` is returned when you're attempting to write a *response* body when no body should be written, as when the response status code is `204`. If you want to return a specific error for *requests* that have a body but shouldn't, then you should be able to write a simple handler middleware that does that, unless the 400/504 is returned by something before your handlers are called.

Comment: as a side note: there are no exceptions to throw in go. Errors are returned from functions and they all have to be handled by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about a go server that you control. You should see this error returned when you call writer.Write() on a HEAD request. You need to handle it in your application by checking for that error. Find where you are calling Write, and check for the error, then display it to the user. You probably need to replace:

```
writer.Write(data)
```

with something like:

```
_,err := writer.Write(data)
```